# Need help inserting info into the database and returning it back

Tags: php

In my code I had three radio buttons that user click to choose the color of each title, text and button that is in hex value. And it is sending info properly, but when the code running that puts everything into the database it's sending user to the to the home page saying that color had been changed, but it did not.

Here's my php code:

```
session_start();

if (isset($_SESSION['username'])) {

include 'databaseconnection.php';

$username = $_SESSION['username'];

$titlecolor = $_POST['titlecolor'];

$textcolor= $_POST['textcolor'];

$buttoncolor = $_POST['buttoncolor'];

$sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='$username'";

$result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);

$resultCheck = mysqli_num_rows($result);

if ($resultCheck < 1) {

    header("Location: index.php?wronghappened");

    exit();

}

else {

    if ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {

        $update = "UPDATE students (titlecolor, `textcolor`, buttoncolor) VALUES (`$titlecolor`, `$textcolor`, `$buttoncolor`) WHERE uname='$uname'";

        $_SESSION['id'] = $row['id'];

        $_SESSION['firstname'] = $row['firstname'];

        $_SESSION['lastname'] = $row['lastname'];

        $_SESSION['email'] = $row['email'];

        $_SESSION['username'] = $row['username'];

        $_SESSION['text'] = $row['text'];

        $_SESSION['title'] = $row['title'];

        $_SESSION['button'] = $row['button'];

        header("Location: home.php?color_changed");

        exit();

    }
}

}

else {

header("Location: index.php?not_in");

exit();

}
```

Comment: Need to see the full code, but i you need to use: '".$titlecolor."' instead of `$titlecolor`

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/367Lj1hy/

Answer (score 0):

You are not using the update query. Excute your update query so it will update the db.

```
$update = "UPDATE students (titlecolor, `textcolor`, buttoncolor) VALUES (`$titlecolor`, `$textcolor`, `$buttoncolor`) WHERE uname='$uname'";

mysql_query($update);
```

Comment: you may want to relook at `...\`$titlecolor\`, \`$textcolor\`, \`$buttoncolor\`...`

Comment: Nothing had been changed

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
  $update = "UPDATE students (titlecolor, `textcolor`, buttoncolor) VALUES (`$titlecolor`, `$textcolor`, `$buttoncolor`) WHERE uname='$uname'";
```

The variable textcolor is being sent to the server as a string, not a variable because you have wrapped it in qoutes. You should only wrap qoutes around strings to be sent as values. Use this instead:

```
  $update = "UPDATE students (titlecolor, textcolor, buttoncolor) VALUES (`$titlecolor`, `$textcolor`, `$buttoncolor`) WHERE uname='$uname'";
```

Then to execute this code, run

```
 mysql_query($con, $update);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$update = "UPDATE students SET titlecolor='$titlecolor', textcolor='$textcolor', buttoncolor='$buttoncolor' WHERE uname='$uname'";
$updateResult = mysqli_query($con, $update);
```

instead of

```
$update = "UPDATE students (titlecolor, `textcolor`, buttoncolor) VALUES (`$titlecolor`, `$textcolor`, `$buttoncolor`) WHERE uname='$uname'";
```

If your will not execute your query using `mysqli_query` then it won't show any effect.

Also I will like to suggest you to use [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) in the future instead of mysqli. For this [reasons](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access--net-12059).
**Happy Coding :)**

Answer (score 0):

Replace your query with this:

```
$updatequery = "UPDATE students set titlecolor='$titlecolor', textcolor='$textcolor', buttoncolor='$buttoncolor' WHERE uname='$uname'";
```

Now Check that is query successfully executed ?

```
if (mysqli_query($con, $updatequery))
{
  echo "successfully execute.....";
//do something here  
}
else
{
echo "Sorry query can't executed!";
echo "My Query ".$updatequery;
}
```

If query not execute then you will see your query after "My Query ", So copy that query and execute it in your mysql then you will find main error.